# GLSL integration function

Tags: opengl-es, sum, glsl, fragment-shader, vertex-shader

Any recommendation on how to implement efficient integral functions, like SumX and SumY, in GLSL shaders?

SumX(u) = Integration with respect to x = I(u0,y) + I(u1,y) +... + I(uN,y); u=normalized x coordinate
SumY(v) = Integration with respect to y = I(x,v0) + I(x,v1) +... + I(x,vN); v=normalized y coordinate

For instance the 5th pixel of the first line would be the sum of all five pixels on the first line.  And the last pixel would be the sum of all previous pixels including the last pixel itself.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

What you are asking for is called [prefix sum](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prefix_sum) or [summed area table (SAT)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table) for the 2D case (just so you find online resources more easily).

Summed area tables can be efficiently implemented on the GPU by decomposing into several parrallel prefix sum passes [[1]](http://developer.amd.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/GDC2005_SATEnvironmentReflections.pdf), [[2]](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/hoppe/recursive.pdf).
The prefix sum can be accelerated by using local memory to store intermediate partial sums (see [example in OpenCL](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/samplecode/OpenCL_Parallel_Prefix_Sum_Example/Listings/scan_c.html) or [example in CUDA](http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems3/gpugems3_ch39.html), the same can in principle be done in an OpenGL fragment shader as well with image load-store, or in a compute shader: [OpenGL Super Bible example](http://books.google.de/books?id=odgdAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT713&lpg=PT713&source=bl&ots=w9SqH_jWQa&q=opengl%20parallel%20prefix%20sum&f=false#v=snippet&q=opengl%20parallel%20prefix%20sum&f=false), similar example to be found in OpenGL Insights around page 280).

Note that you may quickly run into precision issues as the sum may get quite large for the rightmost (downmost) pixels. Integer or fp16 render targets will most likely result in failure due to overflow or lacking precision, fp32 will work most of the time.

Comment: @Damon, may be you know how to implement SAT with OpenGL without compute shader? Super Bible provides the implementation on compute shader, but I'm limited to use OpenGLES2.0 framework.

Comment: @kelin: I think with ES 2.0 it's almost best to do it on the CPU. You would have to render to texture with a pixel shader reading from the larger texture, and seeing how the number of texture fetches that you can do is limited, you will likely need a good number of passes, doing partial sums over smaller areas in each. Much like you create custom mipmaps. Not that you _couldn't_ do that, but it's rather painful.